# fread - multiple separators in a string

Tags: r, text, data.table, separator

I'm trying to read a table using fread.
The txt file has text which look like:

```
"No","Comment","Type"
"0","he said:"wonderful|"","A"
"1","Pr/ "d/s". "a", n) ","B"
```

R codes I'm using is: `dataset0 <- fread("data/test.txt", stringsAsFactors = F)` with the [development version](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) of data.table R package.

Expect to see a dataset with three columns; however:

```
Error in fread(input = "data/stackoverflow.txt", stringsAsFactors = FALSE) : 
Line 3 starting <<"1","Pr/ ">> has more than the expected 3 fields.
Separator 3 occurs at position 26 which is character 6 of the last field: << n) ","B">>. 
Consider setting 'comment.char=' if there is a trailing comment to be ignored.
```

How to solve it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [development version](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) of data.table handles files like this where the embedded quotes have not been escaped. See [point 10 on the wiki page](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Convenience-features-of-fread).

I just tested it on your input and it works.

```
$ more unescaped.txt
"No","Comment","Type"
"0","he said:"wonderful."","A"
"1","The problem is: reading table, and also "a problem, yes." keep going on.","A"

> DT = fread("unescaped.txt")
> DT
   No                                                                  Comment Type
1:  0                                                     he said:"wonderful."    A
2:  1 The problem is: reading table, and also "a problem, yes." keep going on.    A
> ncol(DT)
[1] 3
```

Comment: `fread` is such a smart tool for answering questions on SO where the asker only prints the contents of a data.frame or matrix instead of using `dput()` or providing code to create the data.

Comment: I copy paste the texts to a txt file and used exactly the same code from yours. It still reports the same error.  Tried reinstalled 'data.table' R package, but didn't help.

Comment: @A.Yin See the words "development version" at the start - now linked.

Comment: **used the development version of data.table. Still have problems with this line**: `"1","Pr/ "d/s". "a", n) ","B"` . The error says: `Line 3 starting <<"1","Pr/ ">> has more than the expected 3 fields. Separator 3 occurs at position 26 which is character 6 of the last field: << n) ","B">>. Consider setting 'comment.char=' if there is a trailing comment to be ignored.`

Comment: @A.Yin Ok that's different problem then and a different input by the looks of it.  Please upload the file or reproducible example together with `verbose=TRUE` output to a new [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues).  It works for me with the input in this question.  You have to create a file in this case because pasting the act of pasting it to the command line will mangle it.  That's why the first line is specifically showing `unescaped.txt` in a file.

Answer (score 2):

Use `readLines` to read line by line, then replace delimiter and `read.table`:

```
# read with no sep
x <- readLines("test.txt")

# introduce new sep - "|"
x <- gsub("\",\"", "\"|\"", x)

# read with new sep
read.table(text = x, sep = "|", header = TRUE)

#   No                                                                  Comment Type
# 1  0                                                     he said:"wonderful."    A
# 2  1 The problem is: reading table, and also "a problem, yes." keep going on.    A
```

Comment: @A.Yin then use any character that is not in the text.